# How do I add special characters into a text string using regex.Replace method?

Tags: regex, vbscript, scripting

The first character on every line of a file I have is a comma. How can I remove just this comma?

I have tried to use the replace method but it doesn't seem to accept special characters. Here is an example:

```
            myRegExp.Pattern = "\n,"
            strText5 =myRegExp.Replace(strText4,"\n")
```

The above snipper replaces the first new line char and comma with \n. How can I replace with a special character instead of a literal string?

The MSDN library doesn't seem to have the answers I need.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable `MultiLine` mode (and `Global` if you have not done so) then `^` will match the start of a line:

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "^,"
myRegExp.Multiline = true
myRegExp.Global = true

strText5 = myRegExp.Replace(strText4, "")
```

(In a vanilla VB string there are no escape sequences, `"\n"`
 is just the two *slash*+*n* characters, for a `\n` you would use `vbLf` or `chr(10)`)

Comment: Yeah doesn't surprise me @Alex answering another obvious duplicate question.

Comment: The flagged duplicate isn't what I would have picked, but this is far from the first time someone has asked how to do a regex replace in VBScript.

Comment: Also `\n` is new line so you should use `vbNewLine` to avoid architecture differences. In Windows for example `\n` is equivalent to `vbCrLf` not `vbLf`.